# How to visiualize topmost contributors to a git repo?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to visualize a  pie chart with kibana of the top contributors to a git repo using PR data. I pull all the PRs of a single repo and index the json to ES. A document can look like this

```
{
      "Author" : "palash25",
      "Date" : "2012-10-04T07:52:20Z",
      "Number" : 2539410,
      "IsMerged" : false,
      "MergedBy" : "",
      "Body" : ""
    }
```

This is my kibana setting and the rendered chart:

[image]

It only shows equal slices belonging to authors with just one PR and excludes authors with the most number of PRs.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, I thought a terms aggregation on the author field would seperate all the PR docs into a seperate bucket for each author and then a metric aggregation based on count would return the buckets with the most number of docs but it doesn't seem to happen. What is wrong here?

Am I modelling the json wrong or using the wrong aggregations?

Comment: You mean opened PRs?

Comment: no, and I don't see how that question is relevant

Comment: There should be only one opened PR per user in one git repo. Your chart looks correct to me. Could you please verify that you have count of more than one PR for some users?

Comment: > There should be only one opened PR per user in one git repo


that doesn't make sense to me. Are you saying that in a repo a user is restricted to opening just one PR or are you assuming that the data that I have indexed to elasticsearch has only one PR document for each user then both are wrong

the git repo has collaborators with over 500 PRs too and all that data is in elasticsearch.

And it has data for all PRs open, merged, closed I pulled all of those.

Comment: At a given time a user has only one opened PR. It doesn't make any sense to have many PRs for one repo per one user. Until PR gets closed every commit would be under that opened PR. Since you are pulling not only opened PR, could you please verify that `Stats.Author` field has values of greater than 1?

Comment: No I am not sure how you got that idea but it is wrong and again irrelevant to my question. In case you are looking for proof just check out these two PRs to one repo by the same author  https://github.com/coredns/coredns/pulls/palash25

Comment: Those were from different branches. Could you please provide data I've asked previous comment?